# Add an existing record from a mainform to a subform when you click on the save button

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

Can anyone help as I am struggling to finish the end result:

I got an unbound mainform, got an bound subform, got two tables Masterplant and PlantTransaction.

When I edit a record it shows on the mainform and when I save the record it must duplicate an existing record in the subform, which works, but the trick is that the Opening Hours in the new record must become my Closing Hours of the previous record, everything works it's just the Opening Hours does not show from the Closing hours previous record and the TransactionID is a number field that must auto increment with a different TransactionID number. Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance!!!

Code below:

```
Private Sub cmdSave_Click()
Dim strSQL As String
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
If IsNull(txtOpeningHRS) Then
  Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone
  If rst.RecordCount > 0 Then
    If Me.NewRecord Then
      rst.MoveLast
    Else
      rst.Bookmark = Me.Bookmark
      rst.MovePrevious
    End If
    txtOpeningHRS = rst!CloseHrs
  End If
End If

If IsNull(Me.TransactionID) Or Me.TransactionID = 0 Then
  Me.TransactionID = Nz(DMax("TransactionID", "PlantTransaction") + 1, 1234)
End If

strSQL = "INSERT INTO PlantTransaction(TransactionID, [Plant Number], Opening_Hours, 
[TransactionDate], [FuelConsumption], [Hour Meter Replaced], Comments, [Hours Worked]) & _ 
   strSQL & "VALUES(" & Me.txtTranID & ",'" & Me.txtPlantNo & "','" & Me.txtOpeningHRS & "',#" & 
   Me.txtTransDate & "#,'" & Me.txtFuelConsFuelHr & "','" & Me.txtHrMtrRep & "','" & Me.txtComments   
   & "','" & Me.txtHrsWorked & "');"
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
Me.PlantTransactionQuery.Form.Requery
cmdNew_Click
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Set TransactionID to be an AutoNumber data type, this will automatically increment it.

You can also try replacing:

```
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
Me.PlantTransactionQuery.Form.Requery
```

with:

```
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
Me!PlantTransactionQuery.Form.RowSource = "Select * from PlantTransaction"
Me.PlantTransactionQuery.Form.Refresh
```